# Determine whether subfolders in specified folder path are empty

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do the following:

- find folder based on the path given by a cell value
- determine whether it's subfolders are empty
- if the subfolders are all empty - put "subfolders  empty" in a cell
- if there are some files within any of the subfolders
- put "contains files in a cell"

My code runs but it is skipping over the subfolders sub procedure.

```
Sub search_subfolders()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next


    With Workbooks("Folder_creator.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim Pth As String
        Dim Model As String
        Dim x As String

        Set Rng = .Range("a2:a527")
        Pth = .Range("b2").Value


            For r = 2 To 527

                Model = .Cells(r, 1).Text
                ModelPth = Pth & Model & "\"
                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                ShowSubFolders FSO.ModelPth
                .Cells(r, 4).Value = x
            Next r

        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ShowSubFolders(ModelPth)

    For Each Subfolder In ModelPath.SubFolders
        If Subfolder.Size = 0 Then
        x = "Subfolders empty"
        Else
        x = "Contains files"

        End If
            ShowSubFolders Subfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

I think this is something to do with trying to pass variables to it without the correct syntax.

Comment: a) you are not passing *x* into the sub that assigns a value to it. Pu t `Option Explicit` at the top of your module sheet and then use Alt+D, L to locate all of the missing, orphaned variables. b) the secondary routine keeps overwriting x with a new values over and over. You need to save x to teh worksheet before continuing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there are a number of problems with your code. Please see the code below for something that should work.  I tried to explain changes with comments.  Feel free to comment on this post if you need me to elaborate. Good luck, hope this helps.

Also, I wasn't sure if you wanted to check your ModelPth folder or subfolders in your ModelPth folder, so I made subroutines for both.  I also took the liberty of implementing some small scale error handling.

```
'x needs to be declared here if it is to be accessed by multiple subroutines
Private x As String

Sub search_subfolders()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Removed "On Error Resume next" .... this should only be used very sparingly
    'Slightly better is to only use on a short section followed by "On Error Goto 0"
    'or use "On Error Goto xyz" where "xyz" is a label
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    'Perhaps you do want to refer to a workbook other than the one calling this macro
    'but my guess is that this is intended to run within the workbook calling in
    'in which case, it's much better to use "Activeworkbook" than to rely on a name that may change
    'You may want to also reconsider your use of "Sheet1", you can use Sheets(1) which has it's own problems, or use "ActiveSheet",
    'or just use "Range("B2")" which, is the same as ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
    Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    'If code is housed under a sheet module instead of in a standard module,
    'your best option is to use "Set sheet = Me" and workbook shouldn't need to be specified.
    'If you do ever want to specify calling workbook, you can use "ThisWorkbook"
    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = sheet.Range("A2:A527")
    Dim Pth As String
    Pth = sheet.Range("b2").Value

    Dim Model As String
    'It's really best to avoid using "with" statements... just declare a variable and run with that
    'In this case just make a sheet variable
    For r = 2 To 527
        Model = sheet.Cells(r, 1).Text
        ModelPth = Pth & Model & "\"
        'Are you sure ModelPth is in the correct syntax?
        'That is, youmay want (Pth & "\" & Model & "\") instead.
        CheckSubFolderContent ModelPth
        sheet.Cells(r, 4).Value = x
        CheckFolderContent ModelPth
        sheet.Cells(r, 5).Value = x
    Next r
End Sub

Sub CheckSubFolderContent(ModelPth)
    'Checks for content in subfolders in a folder specified by path
    x = "No Subfolders found"
    'Error handling for Model = ""
    If Right(ModelPth, 2) = "\\" Then
        x = "N/A"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim FSO, Parent As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Parent = FSO.GetFolder(ModelPth)
    If Err > 0 Then
        x = "Error! Parent folder does not exist."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each Subfolder In Parent.SubFolders
        If Subfolder.Size = 0 Then
            x = "Folder has subfolders without content"
        Else
            x = "Folder has subfolders with content"
        End If
        'Why this recursive line? "ShowSubFolders Subfolder"
        'Recursive calls should be avoided and are rarely necesary.
    Next
    If Err > 0 Then x = "Error!"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
Sub CheckFolderContent(ModelPth)
    'Checks for content in a folder specified by path
    x = "No Subfolders found"
    If Right(ModelPth, 2) = "\\" Then
        x = "N/A"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim FSO, Folder As Object
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(ModelPth)
    If Err > 0 Then
        x = "Error! Parent folder does not exist."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Folder.Size = 0 Then
        x = "Folder is empty"
    Else
        x = "Folder has content"
    End If
    If Err > 0 Then x = "Error!"
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I really appreciated all of the comments in there to help me improve future macros myself. A few questions -  why do you prefer `Activeworkbook`?  In the past I have avoided this as I often have numerous workbooks open and I thought vba occasionally went to the wrong sheet - this is why I was using `with` and `.cells.`, but perhaps just `activeworkbook.cells` is enough? Is declaring the sheet as a variable a faster option than using `with`?

Comment: @squarah The reason for avoiding with statements is more for readability than for performance. It's easier to maintain and work with code that avoids them, and languages like C# don't even have them.  It's not like they should always be avoided, like a single line If, sometimes you just want to take shortcuts.  Lots of nested With statements can quickly make your code esoteric (sometimes desirable). I've encountered one very unique situation using VBS where an object could not be created because of how the script was ultimately called from an API, and a With statement was my only option.

Comment: So, I wasn't very precise about workbook & sheet selection because you have so many options and I wasn't sure what other components you may have had.  My main point was just that referring to a Workbook or Sheet by name can be a common point a failure should the name change.  As you pointed out, Active selection or index selection also have their problems.  Thinking about it a little more, I'd suggest you try placing all of the code under a sheet (not in a Module) in the VBA IDE.  Then use this line of code "Set sheet = Me", and "Me" will refer to whatever sheet the code is housed in.

Comment: @squarah I edited my original post to include the comments above about referencing the calling sheet and/or workbook.

Comment: Much much appreciated. I've posted a newer version of the code with a different request [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272484/vba-search-for-files-with-names-containing-string-within-folders-and-subfolders?noredirect=1#comment52428198_32272484) as I thought the next step in the codewas different enough to post it separately

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you are doing wrong.
1. You are trying to access sub-folders without making FSO(FileSystemObject) accessible in `ShowSubFolders` sub.
2. `x` is not global variable and yet you are trying to access it.
3. Less conditions in `ShowSubFolders` sub.

Here is the updated code.

```
Dim FSO As Object    '<-- This one sets FSO global
Dim x As String      '<-- This one sets x global

Sub search_subfolders()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error Resume Next

    Workbooks("Folder_creator.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")

        Dim Rng As Range
        Dim Pth As String
        Dim Model As String

        Set Rng = .Range("a2:a527")
        Pth = .Range("b2").Value

            For r = 2 To 527
                Model = .Cells(r, 1).Text
                ModelPth = Pth & Model & "\"
                Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                ShowSubFolders FSO.GetFolder(ModelPth)
                .Cells(r, 4).Value = x
                x = ""
            Next r

        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    If Folder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
            ShowSubFolders SubFolder
            If SubFolder.Size = 0 Then
                x = "Subfolders empty"
            Else
                x = "Contains files"
            End If
        Next
    Else
        x = "Subfolders empty"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That looks good, however, I'm getting sub or function not defined for `DoFolder` and I'm not sure how to rectify this as I am unsure what DoFolder is?

Comment: It was a typo. I've updated the code. Give it a try now.

Comment: Thanks :). It seems to run but as I need to run it on a VERY slow antiquated server I am remotely connected to, I will need to run it fully overnight and accept your answer in the morning if everything runs smoothly. Cheers!

Comment: So, it ran... but unfortunately the results are incorrect, where it says 'subfolders empty' there are often files contained within. It is very fast so I don't think it is running through all of the subfolders.

Comment: That's weird, because I've tested it on my machine and it works fine. You can try `If SubFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then` instead of `If SubFolder.Size = 0 Then`.